# Angular-gridster: Dynamically add in an Angular 1.5 component from another

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, compilation, components

I've created a dynamic dashboard where widgets can be added,edited and deleted. It is using angular-gridster and directives that dynamically adds other directives by using the link function and $compile. I am now trying to move everything over to components and keep the same dynamic ability.
This is the new main component:-

```
var dashboard = {
templateUrl: 'js/components/dashboard.html',

controller: function () {

this.gridsterOpts = {
  columns: 12,
  margins: [10, 10],
  outerMargin: true,
  pushing: true,
  floating: true,
  swapping: true,
  resizable: {
    enabled: true,
    handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],
  }
};
this.widgets = [
  {

    sizeX: 4,
    sizeY: 3,
    domain: 'COMP1',
    title: 'RTEMS Load',
    component: '<rtems-bullet></rtems-bullet>',
    // content: '<nvd3 options="$ctrl.options" data="$ctrl.result"></nvd3>',
    type: 'AgentsPerRTEMS'
  },
  {

    sizeX: 4,
    sizeY: 3,
    domain: 'COMP1',
    title: 'Agents Per RTEMS',
    component: '<rtems-agents></rtems-agents>',
    // content: '<nvd3 options="$ctrl.options" data="$ctrl.result"></nvd3>',
    type: 'AgentsPerRTEMS'
  },
];
}};

angular
.module('app')
.component('dashboard', dashboard);
```

This dashboard component has the following markup:-

```
    <div gridster="$ctrl.gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in $ctrl.widgets">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {{widget.title}}
                    <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">-->
                        <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                        <!--</button>-->

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="panel-body widget-component">
                        ADD COMPONENT HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to add the component in the panel-body but everytime I try things like {{widget.component}} a string is inserted rather than a dom object - not surprisingly I guess.

Any ideas how I can get the widget.component instantiated as an actual component rather than a literal string?

*** UPDATE ***

I am now trying this as an option :-

```
<div class="panel-body widget-component">  
    <widget-ctrl  dom="widget.domain" widget="widget.component">  
    </widget-ctrl>
</div>
```

The widget attribute holds my component template: .

Is there anyway I can make my widget-ctrl component return the value of the attribute instead of the literal 'widget.component'?

This is the component:

```
var widgetCtrl = {
        transclude: true,
        bindings: {
    widget: '<',
    dom: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    console.log(this.widget);


  },

  template: function ($element, $attrs) {
    console.log($attrs.widget);

    return $attrs.widget;
  },
};

angular
  .module('app')
  .component('widgetCtrl', widgetCtrl);
```

The console.log in the controller function logs out the value of widget whereas the template function logs out the literal. Is there anyway I can change that behaviour?
Thanks for any steer on this.

Comment: I have also tried using a intermediary component like this:-                                <div class="panel-body widget-component">
        <widget-ctrl  widget="widget">{{widget.component}}</widget-ctrl>
 </div>

Comment: I have also tried using a intermediary component like this:- <div class="panel-body widget-component"> <widget-ctrl widget="widget">{{widget.component}}</widget-ctrl> </div> 
 </div> and then using a template function returnswith $attr, an attempt at transcluding it in e.g.  <widget-ctrl  widget="widget">{{widget.component}}</widget-ctrl> and one last try using a service in my template function. I'm still missing something so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.